# Does "Swarm" AI card affect all Locust on the map?

Tags: gears-of-war

In the Gears of War board game there are AI cards.  These cards generally refer to AI's that fit a specific criteria (like "all wretch with 3 spaces").  However the Swarm card reads:

> Each Locust that is 5 or more moment away from the nearest COG figure moves until it is 4 movement away from the nearest COG figure

Does this mean all Locust that aren't near you pile up in one spot that is 4 away from where you are standing?

[image]

[Source](http://boardgamegeek.com/image/1095634/gears-of-war-the-board-game)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is part of the game mechanics to bring the distant locust back into the game. Most of the "For Each" Locust AI cards only move the figures one or two areas and only spawn Locust if there are no figures in play of the listed type. Rules of play book suggest that if there is no space to place the piece off the edge of the map.

With that said it could be possible to have Locust type A, B, and C at the far end of the map with minimal effects on the player from Locust AI card if there was no card like this.

Comment: you might want to note that the active player might have a choice   of where to place the figures, so if two spaces are equidistant. all the figures may not be in the same space.